# Причины явной реализации членов интерфейса

Tags: c#

Шилдт описывает две причины явной реализации членов интерфейсов, но мне не понятна одна из них. Вот, что он пишет: когда интерфейсный метод реализуется с указанием его полного имени, то такой метод оказывается доступным не посредством объектов класса, реализующего данный интерфейс, а по интерфейсной ссылке. Следовательно, явная реализация позволяет реализовать интерфейсный метод таким образом, чтобы он не стал открытым членом класса, предоставляющего его реализацию. Мне не понятно смысл описанного и причина когда это нужно использовать и зачем? В книге приводится следующий пример, такжн я пометил комментарии что мне не понятно также в коде:

```
interface IEven { 
      bool IsOdd(int x); 
      bool IsEven(int x); 
    }

    class MyClass : IEven {

      bool IEven.IsOdd(int x) { 
        if((x%2) != 0) return true; 
        else return false; 
      }

      // Normal implementation. 
      public bool IsEven(int x) { 
        IEven o = this; //объясните данный участок кода

        return !o.IsOdd(x); 
      } 
    }

    class Demo { 
      static void Main() { 
        MyClass ob = new MyClass(); 
        bool result;

        result = ob.IsEven(4); 
        if(result) Console.WriteLine("4 is even.");

        // result = ob.IsOdd(4); // Error, IsOdd not exposed.

        IEven iRef = (IEven) ob; // объясните данный участок кода
        result = iRef.IsOdd(3); 
        if(result) Console.WriteLine("3 is odd."); 
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

В целом, это нужно именно тогда, когда вызов метода интерфейса непосредственно у объекта не предусмотрен. Например, этот метод нужен Вашей внутренней инфраструктуре, а прикладной программист, который использует Ваш объект, об этом знать не должен.

Второй случай - это если интерфейс реализован не полностью. Например, класс `ControlCollection` реализует `IList`, в котором объявлен метод `Insert`, но сам этот метод не реализует. Чтобы у прикладного программиста не возникало соблазна его вызвать, метод таким способом спрятан. Если попытаться его вызвать, приведя экземпляр `ControlCollection` к `IList`, метод бросит `NotSupportedException`.

Ещё один достаточно типичный вариант использования явной реализации интерфейса - это когда класс реализует несколько интерфейсов, члены которых конфликтуют по именам. Например, все стандартные коллекции в `.NET` реализуют как `ICollection`, так и `ICollection<T>`. Большинство членов `ICollection` в этих классах реализовано явно.